# How to execute a function every time the content is changed in an input field using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, input

I have a text field `<input type="text" id="search" />` and I would like to execute a JavaScript function every time the user change the content in it (letter by letter). How can I do this using jQuery?

I tried to implement the function as the answer to [Using JQuery, how do you detect if the value of a text input has changed while the field still has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539279/using-jquery-how-do-you-detect-if-the-value-of-a-text-input-has-changed-while-th/1539375#1539375) but nothing happens for me.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/search.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<form>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" /> 
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

My search.js is:

```
var target = $('#search'), val = target.val();

function search()
{
    alert('search');
}

target.keyup(search);
```

I have also tried with (nothing happens):

```
$('input[name=search]').change(function() {
    alert('changed');
})
```

And if I try just adding some HTML using jQuery, it works:

```
$(function(){
    $("<p>hello</p>").insertAfter("#search");
})
```

Comment: The element has id `search`, not `itemsearch`, and you always have to put the code inside `$(function(){...})` if you want to access DOM elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change event doesn't fire until the control loses focus. If you are only interested in text, you can use [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) to do something before the contents change,  or [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) to do something afterwards.

Here is an example using keypress in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R6vmZ/

Comment: `keyup` would be better, as the keypress event fires *before* the contents of the field are changed.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I have updated my answer to indicate both methods.